# Spatial media injection

Tags: java, android, c, spatial

Recently i come across a library for **spatial media injection** [here](https://github.com/cievon/spatial-media) ,after a long search. This library is a copy of spatial media injection by google [here](https://github.com/google/spatial-media). Google developed this in python scrpit and the first mention library is C files which i can use in android. I successfully injected spatial video but the video is not injected by spatial Audio that is, Ambisonic audio.
I am looking for help if anyone successfully injected the spatial audio.
This is the starting code for injection

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "parser.h"
#include "metadata_utils.h"
#include "mpeg/box.h"

using namespace std;

#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>
//int parsefile(string in,string out);
extern "C" {
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_com_blackbox_ffmpeg_examples_tools_video_VideoTrimmer_trimvideo(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance, jstring inputfile, jstring outputfile) {
// TODO
SpatialMedia::Parser parser;
parser.getInFile() = "/storage/emulated/0/360 videos/inject_pre.mov";
parser.getOutFile()= "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/test.mov";
if ( parser.getInFile ( ) == "" )  {
    cout << "Please provide an input file." << endl;
    exit ( -1 );
}

Utils utils;
if ( parser.getInject ( ) )  {
    if ( parser.getOutFile ( ) == "" )  {
        cout << "Injecting metadata requires both input and output file." << endl;
        exit ( -2 );
    }
    Metadata md;
    std::string &strVideoXML = utils.generate_spherical_xml ( parser.getStereoMode ( ), parser.getCrop ( ) );
    md.setVideoXML ( strVideoXML );
   if ( parser.getSpatialAudio ( ) )
        md.setAudio ( &g_DefAudioMetadata );

    if ( strVideoXML.length ( ) > 1 ) {
        utils.inject_metadata(parser.getInFile(), parser.getOutFile(), &md);
      /*  Box *pAudioMediaAtom = new Box() ;
        std::fstream inFile ( parser.getInFile().c_str ( ), std::ios::in | std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate );
        pAudioMediaAtom->load(inFile,0,inFile.end);
        utils.inject_spatial_audio_atom(inFile, pAudioMediaAtom,  &g_DefAudioMetadata );
*/        } else
            cout << "Failed to generate metadata." << endl;
    }

return 0;
}

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_blackbox_ffmpeg_examples_tools_video_VideoTrimmer_stringFromJNI(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    string hello = "Hello from C++";
    return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
}
}
```